# Fix Value of Row or Column from Another Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

In a given sheet, if you have a formula that involves a value, it's possible to fix either the column or row for that value as you expand the equation, i.e. :

```
=A1 + A!2
```

But how do you do this when one of those values is from another sheet? You'd think it would be something like:

```
=A1 + 'OtherSheet'!A!2
```

but this doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Try using a `$` in stead of a `!` for the second exclamation mark.....

Comment: Oh man... yea. (facepalm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only use the exclamation point following the sheet name, not the cell -

`=A1 + 'Other Sheet'!A$2`

Use dollar signs for absolute references.